# show list of filename and paths on local directory/ folder

Tags: javascript, html, jscript

im trying to make a video library on my local computer that shows a list of sub-folders then shows the video links

i found a couple codes but none seem to be working now i am rather new in js php jquery and any help would be great

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Show Local Folder File List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<script type="text/JScript">
//note this is JScript, not javascript. Thus the 'type="text/JScript"' in the script tags
function ShowFolderFileList(folderspec){
var fso, f, fc, s;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec);
fc = new Enumerator(f.files);
s = "";
for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
s += fc.item();
s += "<br>";
}
return s;
}
//note folder/file paths should use the local windows style backslash and be escaped '\\' :
var fileList = ShowFolderFileList('C:\\vids');
document.write(fileList);
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say local, do you mean server or Client. Let me clear things first. When you are developing the client and server are same. After deploying the client's machine is different then server machine.

Comment: ActiveX technology only works in some versions of Internet Explorer. Outside of that, this cannot be done as it is a security issue.

Comment: @Aditya *When you are developing the client and server are same.* Uh no. The client is the software the receives the response. The server is the software that sends it. You can (and should) have both running on your own local machine during development as there are many APIs that don't work when you are developing against the file system (Geolocation, AJAX). Even some HTML requires an HTTP call to work (the `download` attribute) so developing against a server is always a best-practice.

Comment: *//note this is JScript, not javascript. Thus the 'type="text/JScript"' in the script tags* JScript and JavaScript are just brand names, but it was never correct to use `text/jscript`. `text/javascript` was the correct thing to use not `text/jscript` and these days, you can omit that completely as `text/javascript` is the default.

Comment: I meant the client machine and server machine. If you have server probably the web server in your case installed local to the system you are developing on, and the browser you see the response on, then client and server machine are same.

Comment: My bad. misunderstood that

Comment: @Aditya Even when they are both installed on the same "box", we still refer to them as being separate things.

Comment: Yeah I got you. But the machine is same right? The client machine and server machine?

Comment: @Aditya It *can* be but doesn't have to be. Often, it is.

Comment: as a local i mean my personal desktop

Comment: basically i want to have a html page on my desktop that shows the folders contents in a list format

folder 1 
  vid 1
  vid 2
folder 2 
  vid 3
  vid 4

Comment: It would be easier to implement that one in php

Comment: true but that would work if i had the files on a server but im trying to run the code or page locally on my desktop non server to get a list of the videos in a folder in my C:/vids/

Comment: after more searching i came across https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2013/11/21/how-to-generate-directory-index-files/
works so far but it places a extra / in front of  http://vids//index.html index.html